# Simultaneous Equations from Quadratic Formula without Calculator

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, quadratics

From $ax^2+bx+c$ (quadratic formula)
$3$ points $(5,500), (3,375), (12,980)$ I solved
$$25a+5b+c=500$$
$$9a+3b+c=375$$
$$144a+12b+c=980$$
My question: Is it possible to solve it without a calculator (for the simulateneous equations)
If yes, How can I do it?

Comment: Please typeset using *MathJax*.

Comment: How can I do it? Is there a method?

Comment: search for the row reduction method

Comment: https://textbooks.math.gatech.edu/ila/row-reduction.html

Comment: You could use pencil and paper.

Answer (score 2):

$$25a+5b+c=500 \tag 1$$
$$9a+3b+c=375\tag 2$$
$$144a+12b+c=980\tag 3$$
$$(1)-(2) \implies 16a+2b=125 \tag 4$$
$$(3)-(1) \implies 119a+7b=480 \tag 5$$
$$7 \times (4)\implies 112a+14b=875\tag 6$$
$$2 \times (5)\implies 238a+14b=960\tag 7$$
$$(7)-(6) \implies 126a=85 \implies a=\frac{85}{126}$$ Go back to $(4)$ to get $b$ and then to $(1)$ to get $c$.

Comment: @moo. Guess what ? a typo ! Cheers :-(